# How can I create a form post that will take a name some one posted and forward to a url ie http://chat.playio.net/index.php?autojoin=Usercreateddata

Tags: php, irc, chatroom

I was trying to make a simple form where some one can enter a chatroom name they wanted and hit create button and it will forward them to a url. Exp. I wanted to create a chatroom called music. I type in music and hit the create button. The page then forwards me to

`http://chat.playio.net/index.php?autojoin=music`

I am kind of new at this.

Comment: What you have tried? Please show us your code.

Comment: <form method="POST" name="create" target="_blank">
  <p>Enter the name of the room you like to create</p>
  <p><input type="text" name="roomname" size="20"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Create" name="B1"></p>
</form>

Not really sure after that. I been googling for a few days trying to learn. Not really sure if I am looking for the right thing, Or calling it the right thing

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simplest of form as follows:

```
<form action="http://chat.playio.net/index.php" method="get">
    <input name="autojoin" id="autojoin" />
    <input type="button" name="Go" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why use javascript for something build-in?

Comment: Bcoz then i have to use input type submit instead of button, and it will also get passed as param then.

Comment: Not if you omit the `name` parameter.

Comment: @steve please add <input type="submit" value="submit"/> instead of button in above form

Answer (score 0):

Simple, no PHP needed:

```
<form action="http://chat.playio.net/index.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="autojoin" />
     <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eKEWU/)

The trick is that you use a `GET` request to the target site. This will append all form values to the URL in the way you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! ugh I suck.